# Disable automatic point hover when entering chart with mouse

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Try hovering the chart are somewhere. You will notice that it automatically triggers hover event for the appropriate x value on the chart.

Even though we haven't even hovered over the line itself.

I would like to disable it. I want to trigger hover event only when the hover happened on the lite itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Rakesh_V_R/ykn77Lmw/13/

Added these series options:

```
type: 'scatter',
stickyTracking: false,
lineWidth: 2,
```